# What is the best strategy to handle exception in spring amqp SimpleMessageListenerContainer

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have two confusions.

1.If RuntimeException thrown from message listener, does SimpleMessageListenrContainer stop?
2.If SimpleMessageListenerContainer not stop, what is behavior about the auto acknowledgement?

Currently, I want that if the message listener handle message failed, i just log the error and don't stop the container meanwhile notify the broker have received message.

Now I just catch the throwable in message listener method, is it the right way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the container won't stop.

If the listener throws an exception, the message is rejected (and requeued by default). You can change the default behavior to discard the message by setting `defaultRequeueRejected` to false (it's true by default). Or throw an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` which instructs the container to reject (and not requeue) the message - the ack is sent as if the listener had thrown no exception.

When a message is rejected without requeuing, it is either discarded or sent to the dead letter exchange, if the queue is so configured.

Comment: why default value is true?what is the behavior when use default config?Is the message will requeue infinite times?

Comment: another question, how to config deadletter exchange, i don't see any clue about it.

Comment: Yes it will keep requeing unless you add a retry advice to give up after some number of delivery attempts.  `>why default true?` - it's a `boolean`; some others would say `why false?` - we had to choose one and it seems that not losing messages is the best default. `another question` - It's better to ask a new question rather than commenting on an existing one. See the [RabbitMQ documentation about dead letter queues and exchanges](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html).

Comment: @GaryRussell It shouldn't be any difference between throwing `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`  and `ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException`, yeah ? In both cases message is resend to DLX (if configured). yeah ?  I can see that in  case of `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`  it doesn't require `defaultRequeueRejected`, however when we send ack there is no chane for requeuing.

Comment: @HaskellFun - you HAVE TO STOP HIJACKING these old answers - this is all completely explained by the loooooong discussion on my answer to [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43018932/dlx-in-rabbitmq-and-spring-rabbitmq-some-considerations-of-rejecting-messages).