# DLX in rabbitmq and spring-rabbitmq - some considerations of rejecting messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I did read this reference: https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html, however it doesn't resolve my doubts, namely:
In case of accepting message there is no problem - `spring-rabbitmq` send ack and everthing is fine, `DLX` doesn't know about acked message.

The problem is in case rejecting answer, namely what about throwing `MessageConverterException` ?  This message is removed or moved to `DLX`?

And what about in case other exception ? For example `Exception` ?  It is removed/requeued/moved to `DLX` ?

**Edit after answer of @Gary**
I think, that after answer's @Gary I should add more details about my case and some summary of @Gary's answer. @Gary exactly grasped my use case.

I wouldn't like requeue - never (I am afraid of looping), but I wouldn't like to lose messages when an exception was thrown  (for example lost connection to database) - this message should be resend to `DLX`. On the other hand,  conversion of message should be treated as fatal error - no requeue, no resend to DLX - simply permanent removing message. **Generally, in depends on exception either reject (=resend to DLX if configured) or accept, never requeue.**

To sum up in a nutshell approach proposed by @Gary.
**First**: We can override `ExceptionHandler` to manage of sending nack/ack, which gives to us a full control.
**Second**: IMO simpler, solution is to set `defaultRequeueRejected=false`  and in converter throw `ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException`. It makes that `RabbitMQ` think that answer was accepted (the same thing as in case of first solution), moreover listener wouldn't be invoked.  
`**Conclusion**: Using`ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException`or`ExceptionHandler` exception we have a full control on permanent rejecting message (under hood ack)  and resending to DLX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ knows nothing about the exceptions.

When the container catches an exception it calls `channel.basicReject(deliveryTag, requeue)`.

If requeue is true, the message is requeued.

By default, for any exception other than those mentioned [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#exception-handling)

> o.s.amqp...MessageConversionException
>
> o.s.messaging...MessageConversionException
>
> o.s.messaging...MethodArgumentNotValidException
>
> o.s.messaging...MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException

`requeue` is set to true, so the message is requeued.

For those exceptions, the delivery is considered fatal and the message is NOT requeued, it will go to a DLX/DLQ if one is configured.

The container has a flag `defaultRequeueRejected` which is true by default; if you set it to `false`; no exceptions will be requeued.

For application-level exceptions, generally, messages will be requeued. To dynamically reject (and not requeue) a message, make sure there is an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` in the cause chain. This instructs the container to not requeue the message, and it will go to the DLX/DLQ (if configured). This behavior is enabled by the `defaultRequeueRejected` flag mentioned above.

This is all explained in the documentation and, as I have discussed in other answers to you, you can change this behavior by using a custom error handler; that, too, is explained in the documentation.

It is not possible to send some exceptions to the DLX/DLQ and not others; rabbit only has a binary option, requeue or don't requeue and, for the latter, if a DLX/DLQ is configured all such rejected messages go to the DLX/DLQ.

Spring AMQP provides one more exception, `ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException`. If your listener throws this exception, the message will be ack'd as if it was processed successfully (`channel.basicAck()`). That is the only technique provided by the container, to discard a bad message without sending it to the DLX/DLQ.

Of course, your application can drop such messsages itself.

If you want to DLX/DLQ all business exceptions but drop conversion exceptions, throw `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` (or set `defaultRequeueRejected` to false), and throw `ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException` from your converter.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. I edited my post to clarify issue and sum up your ideas.  What approach (`ExceptionHandler` or `ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException` shoudl be used ? IMO `ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException` because it is simpler and give full control.

Comment: It's your choice; for a custom converter it's probably easier/simpler to do it there, and use the standard error handler. If you anticipate using other converters as well, and want the same behavior, a custom error handler might be better. But your analysis in your edit is correct.

Comment: when it comes to `ErrorHandler` - what funciton should be overriden (keep in mind DLX configured) ? I think that `isFatal` can help here. We should set `defaultRequeueRejected=false` to block requeing on the whole.  Then, returning true from `isFatal` we ensure that message won't be resend to `DLX`, simply permanent removing. When we return from `isFatal` false, it automatically will be resend to `DLX`. Yeah ?

Comment: I would recommend a custom `ErrorHandler` rather than trying to make the `ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler` meet your needs - it is designed solely to analyze the exception to determine whether the message should be requeued or not. You need additional functionality - decide whether to consume the message after an exception, or not. A simple `ErrorHandler` with `defaultRequeueRejected=false` is the way to go.

Comment: So what should be overriden ? `handleError` from     `DefaultErrorHandler`  ?

Comment: Just implement `ErrorHandler`.

Comment: is there some example about customing `ErrorHandler` ?

Comment: Sigh - the `DefaultErrorHandler` is a decent example.

Comment: Ok, I will read this and edit my question to again sum up these considerations. *When a listener throws an exception, it is wrapped in a ListenerExecutionFailedException* - does it mean that each message (such that for **any** exception thrown from listener) wil be resend to `DLX` (if configured). Yeah ?

Comment: Unbelievable!!! It should be clear now what you need to do; you must stop keep asking new questions here - ask a new question if there's still something you don't understand!!!!

Comment: Ok, simply I would like to make sure about it. Yes, it was obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I successfully implemented queus with dlx, but at this moment all rejected messages are resended to `DLX`, althgough I throw from converter  `MessageConversionException`. In the stacktrace I can see ListenerExecutionFailedException - why ? After all, I throw an exception from converter. Morevoer, requeue=false is always set.

Comment: I found a issue: I must write my own HandlerError and from handleError throw Immediate...