# Avoid sending message to DLQ/DLX

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

Our application is using org.springframework.cloud, spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit framework and we are trying to avoid sending specific messages to DLQ and also retrying them, this behaviour should be somehow dynamically, because, for the default messages, retries and DLQ should work.

According to this documentation:

[Putting it All Together](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Chelsea.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#_putting_it_all_together)

And this useful post:

[DLX in rabbitmq and spring-rabbitmq - some considerations of rejecting messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43018932/dlx-in-rabbitmq-and-spring-rabbitmq-some-considerations-of-rejecting-messages)

It seems that `ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException` could be used in spring AMQP to mark a message as acknowledged and no further process it. However, when we use this code:

```
@StreamListener(LogSink.INPUT)
public void handle(Message<Map<String, Object>> message) {

    if (message.getPayload().get("condition1").equals("abort")) {
        throw new ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException("error, we don't want to send this message to DLQ");
    }

    ...
}
```

The message is always send to DLQ

Our current configuration:

```html
spring.cloud.stream:
  bindings:
    log:
      consumer.concurrency: 10
      destination: log
      group: myGroup
      content-type: application/json
  rabbit.bindings:
    log:
      consumer:
        autoBindDlq: true
        republishToDlq: true
        transacted: true
```

Are we missing something? Is there any other alternative to avoid publishing to DLQ and requeuing?

Answer (score 1):

`republishToDlq` does not look at that exception; it only applies when the exception is thrown to the container (method `causeChainHasImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException()`).

Republishing subverts that logic since no exception is thrown to the container.

Please open an issue against the Rabbit binder, `republishToDlq` should honor that exception and discard the failed message.